# Unable to get an element animation to wait for another in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you go to an album (eg. Nature because still working on the others) and click one of the images they all fade out and then the one you clicked appears to just show up on the screen. What is happening is that it is still fading in as the thumbnails are fading out. I tried adding the rest of the code inside a .complete(), but that seems to break it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('.photos').on('click', function() {

    var src = $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb-','');
    $('.photos').stop().fadeOut(500);
        $('.enlarged').remove();
        $('#album').append('<img class="enlarged" src="' + src + '">');
        $('.enlarged').hide();
        $('.enlarged').stop().fadeIn(500).done(
            $('.enlarged').on('click', function () {

                $(this).stop().fadeOut({

                    duration: 500,
                    done: this.remove()
                });

                $('.photos').stop().fadeIn(500);

            })
        );
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) to catch complete all fade out animation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.photos').on('click', function() {

    var src = $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb-','');
    var photos = $('.photos');
    photos.stop().fadeOut(500);

    photos.promise().done( function() {
        $('.enlarged').remove();
        $('#album').append('<img class="enlarged" src="' + src + '">');
        $('.enlarged').hide();
        $('.enlarged').stop().fadeIn(500).done(
            $('.enlarged').on('click', function () {

                $(this).stop().fadeOut({    
                    duration: 500,
                    done: this.remove()
                });

                $('.photos').stop().fadeIn(500);

            })
        );
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: So by adding the .promise().done(...); It's basically saying "When this is done animating, do this function"? Whats the difference between just .done()?

Comment: `$('.photos').fadeOut(500)` - is not one animation, but the animation collection elements. Promise allows you to track the end of all the animations that can end at different times.